# Ruby defined?( 42[0][:foo] ) && defined?( 93[0]["bar"] ) == true. Why?

Tags: ruby, defined

Short story:

### "Why does `defined?(59[0][:whatever])` evaluate to true?"

---

Long story:

I came across some strange behaviour lately which threw me off.

I was developing a method that did some washing of the data:

```
#Me washing input data:
def foo(data)
  unless data && defined?(data[0]) && defined?(data[0][:some_param])
    method2(data[0][:some_param])
  else
    freak_out()
  end
end
```

I usually write tests where I spew in all kinds of junk data to make sure nothing strange happens:

```
describe "nice description" do
  it "does not call method2 on junk data" do
    expect(some_subject).to_not receive(:method2)
    random_junk_data_array.each do |junk|
      some_subject.foo(junk)
    end
  end
end
```

Well, `method2` was called here. It happened when `junk` was a fixnum.

I am using `ruby 2.1.0`, and I can see that `Fixnum` has a `#[]` method which fetches the bit at that position, nice.

But why is `fixnum[0][:some_param]` considered to be `defined`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [`defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) expression **tests whether or not expression refers to anything recognizable** (literal object, local variable that has been initialized, method name visible from the current scope, etc.). The return value is `nil` if the **expression cannot be resolved.** Otherwise, the return value provides information about the expression.

Let me explain with an example :-

```
defined?("a") # => "expression"
# this returns "method", as there is a method defined on the class String. So, the
# method invocation is possible, and this is a method call, thus returning `"method"`.
defined?("a".ord) # => "method"
# it return nil as there is no method `foo` defined on `"a"`, 
# so the call is not possible.
defined?("a".foo) # => nil
```

Now coming to your point :-

As you said `data[0]` gives a `Fixnum` instance, and of-course [`Fixnum#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D) exist. Thus `fixnum_instance[:some_param]` is also a valid method call. It just testing if the method is defined or not. If defined, it will tell yes *this is a `"method"` expression. Otherwise `nil`. Not actually will check if the method call succeeded or not.*

In Ruby all objects has *truthy* values except `nil` and `false`, thus `"method"` being a string object also has the *truthy* value, thus your condition got succeeded.

Comment: Yeah. `3[0][:whatever]` produces an error, but the error *isn’t* that the method is undefined.

Comment: I get it. It's essentially a `begin catch` which checks for `not defined error` only, and returns nil if it catches it, or some form of "true" if it doesn't.